# Show that $\frac{3\sqrt{\tau+ 2}}{\sqrt{9\tau + 6}} = \sqrt{3(7 - 4\tau)} = \sqrt{\frac{15}{4\tau + 3}}$

Tags: geometry

The exercise is stated above.
$\tau$ is the positive solution of the equation $x^2 - x - 1$ which is the equation of the golden ratio.

When I simplify, I get
$\frac{\sqrt{3\tau + 6}}{\sqrt{3\tau + 2}}$ and when I instead substitute $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ for $\tau$, I also don't get anything near the second expression in the equation.

$\frac{3\sqrt{\tau+ 2}}{\sqrt{9\tau + 6}}$ is also the ratio of inradius / circumradius of the icosahedron.

Do you guys have any hints (not full solutions) in order to solve this?

Comment: Yes it is, but I misworded my explanation of what $\tau$ is. It is the positive solution $x^2 - x - 1$ which is the equation of the golden ratio.

Comment: I edited my post. Now it should be the correct description.

Comment: 1/ To clarify, for $ 3 \sqrt{\tau } + 2$, is it $ 3 \sqrt{ \tau + 2 } $? These are very different expressions, and you have it written in both ways. 2/ You still haven't fixed the incorrect claim that $ \tau = \frac{ 1 + \sqrt{15 } } { 2} $.

Comment: What about using a calculator to check first instead of diving deep into symbol manipulation?

Comment: Sorry guys. I had a lot of typos when I translated things into latex. The post is hopefully stated correctly now.

Comment: Hint for the first equality: don't "substitute $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ for $\tau$". Instead, expand $(7-4\tau)(3\tau+2)$ and simplify (using that $\tau^2=\tau+1$), to check that it equals $\tau+2.$ Same method for the second equality.

Comment: What's the sense of all those roots? Just square the whole thing and get rid of those root-signs :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMMENT.-One has $\tau=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ so
$$\frac{3\sqrt{\tau+ 2}}{\sqrt{9\tau + 6}}=\frac{3\sqrt{5+\sqrt5}}{\sqrt{21+9\sqrt5}}= \frac{3\sqrt{(5+\sqrt5)(21-9\sqrt5)}}{21^2-5\times9^2}= \frac12\sqrt{60-24\sqrt5}=\sqrt{3(5-2\sqrt5)}$$ Is it true that $5-2\sqrt5=7-4\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)$? The answer is yes which is easily verified.

Similarly for the other equality (it is just an exercise of simplification).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $t$ is a root of $x^2-x-1=0, t^2=t+1$

Using this,
$$(7-4t)(9t+6)=3(7-4t)(3t+2)=\cdots=3(t+2)$$

$$\implies\dfrac{t+2}{9t+6}=?$$

As all the terms are $>0,$  take root in both sides

Similarly, $$(7-4t)(4t+3)=21+16t-16(t+1)=5\implies7-4t=?$$